# kivy grid layout change column/row sizes

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, grid-layout

I have a grid layout with 2 columns, i would like to do something like:

```
for a grid layout of size x, y:
column 1 has width = 0.8 * x, 
column 2 has width = 0.2 * x.
```

all rows should be the same, i still want my grid layout to be sized dynamically so i don't want to explicitly set dimensions.
I have tried setting size_hint and width for individual buttons in the grid but that basically breaks the grid layout.
Is there an easy way to do this for all elements in a column(or row) at once in a kv file?

Comment: You can use [`cols_minimum`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.cols_minimum).

Comment: this does not set the ratio of the column widths, only minimum width for each column.

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).